# Golang - do libraries need to be non-blocking?

Tags: node.js, go, tornado, eventmachine

My understanding is that non-blocking web servers (node.js, eventmachine, tornado) can grind to a halt if they make a call to a blocking library. Is this true for Golang as well? If one goroutine gets blocked, is another one automatically given access to the CPU, or do they have to wait for the blocked goroutine to 'yield'? If it is the former, then libraries don't need to be non-blocking, do they? I ask because I haven't seen any Redis/Mongo libraries that explicitly state that they're non-blocking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My understanding is that non-blocking web servers (node.js,
>   eventmachine, tornado) can grind to a halt if they make a call to a
>   blocking library. Is this true for Golang as well?

No it isn't. Go routines will yield on IO or the runtime will create new OS threads as necessary.

> If one goroutine gets blocked, is another one automatically given
>   access to the CPU

Yes it is - go routines yield on any sort of IO or channel communication.

> or do they have to wait for the blocked goroutine to 'yield'?

No they don't.

> If it is the former, then libraries don't need to be non-blocking, do
>   they? I ask because I haven't seen any Redis/Mongo libraries that
>   explicitly state that they're non-blocking.

No libraries (or Go code in general) don't need to be non blocking which makes them much easier to write and maintain.  This is a major plus point of Go in my opinion. The runtime does the clever bit running 1000s of go routines and you just write simple imperative code.

Comment: So if a goroutine gets blocked, it doesn't block the entire thread (that it's sharing with other goroutines)? If this is the case, the only time you'd need to write callback code is when you want that particular goroutine to continue, and not switch to another one (which is pretty rare I'm guessing)?

Comment: You don't use callbacks for that. You'll put the "thing that blocks" in a separate goroutine and then use channels for it to "talk back" when it's done.

Comment: @Nick your triple negative is hard to understand, please clarify. ("No libraries...")

Comment: A good answer, Nick. The current fad for asynchronous I/O has grown out of limited capabilities of various runtimes, notably the JVM. Go makes life much easier for developers by breaking out of that particular constraint. (Occam has similar intent)

Comment: @Tom, I think he meant to put a comma after No, ie, No, libraries don't need to be non-blocking. Libraries can be blocking because even if a goroutine blocks, other goroutines still have access to the CPU. This is in stark contrast to node, event machine, tornado etc where only one thread has access to the CPU, and hence should never block.